# How to find different combinations of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array

```
[[0 6 0 0]
[0 7 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 7 0 0]
[3 4 6 0]
[2 1 4 0]
[3 1 2 0]
[3 1 2 0]
[0 1 2 0]
[1 7 1 3]
[0 3 6 7]]
```

I want to get the combinations like:

```
  1.[0 0 0 0 0 3 2 3 3 0 1 0]
  2.[6 6 7 1 7 4 1 1 1 1 7 3]
  3.[0 0 0 0 0 6 4 2 2 2 1 6]
  4.[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 7]
  5.[[0 6]
  [0 7]
  [0 1]
  [0 7]
  [3 4]
  [2 1]
  [3 1]
  [3 1]
  [0 1]
  [1 7]
  [0 3]]
```

and so on..

How can we do this in a loop?

Comment: why do you want a loop absolutely?

Comment: Is there any other way to perform this?

Comment: using list comprehension (which is kind of a loop) but above all using itertools, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

t = np.random.rand(4,3) # dummy example np.array
n_cols = t.shape[1] # number of columns

# all the combinations in a tuple:
combs = tuple( t[:, comb] for n in range(n_cols+1) for comb in combinations(range(n_cols), n) )
```

This gets all combinations of columns of length `n` for all (sensible) values of `n`.

Comment: You're welcome! If that solved your question completely, please mark the answer as accepted, otherwise please let us know what you're still missing.